# Is there any benchmark about the speed of blocks search engines?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I want to know the performance of search engines such as blockchain.info, smartbit or blockr.io I know that they are very speed but I want a real benchmark that gives the actual speed (in seconds or milliseconds) of a research operation by block number or address.

If no benchmark exists, could you, please, guide me on the necessary steps to follow in order to make such a benchmark?

Thanks.

Comment: You will not find such benchmark . However, to realise it i think you will define some comparaison elements such as rhe provided services or the speed of tx listing. You could send a transaction and compare the delay of the confirmation in bitcoin or etherum client and the listing in these explorer.

Comment: I am not looking for the confirmation time of a transaction, but the required time to search and look-up in a blockchain, which can be locally stored.

Comment: if I want to search for a particular address in a blockchain, how much times it will take this operation?

Comment: I was not talking about confirmation time but the "listing time" of a confirmed transaction in these explorer (e.g it could be listed as confirmed in a one explorer while it isn't in another). I think you first should read about how these explorer works and about the delay of transmission withing a blockchain network.

Comment: The main thing in these explore is the indexing method,

Comment: i suggest you to look at github.com/etherparty/explorer and leveldb if you are from morocco drop me an email at bellaj.badr@gmail.com